# Is it possible to use SQL functions in Sort.Order in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

We have a query where we need to run a MySQL Function to get correct Order By results. We are using Spring Data JPA and the Where clause is made up of a Specification. The pagination and sorting is done by a Pageable instance. So I need to be able to pass the MySQL function convert() to the Sort.Order object in order to correctly sort our results. Since we use pagination, we need to be able to put that into the Sort.Order object. Is it possible?

I tried countless Google Searches, and all I would get is the high level documentation of Spring Data, or the result set would all just be about MySQL.

Comment: I found this, but I have to see if we are up to that version.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/b8e7fe

Comment: How would you do that in SQL? Can you show your SQL statement?

Comment: SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY CONVERT(some_table.some_field, SIGNED INTEGER)

Comment: Regarding my link, we are on an older version of Spring Data JPA and do not have access to use that object. Upgrading right now would be a month or 2 operation for us with changing, testing and such that upgrading is NOT an option.

Comment: this is not possible with Spring Data you should either use JPQL or SQL.

Comment: Ouch, trying to convert the Specification into a String will take quite some time. But I understand, I read too that said that Spring Data could not. UNLESS you have a more recent version and can use JpaSort.unsafe(). Thanks for you help Simon.